# Maintain the height of <td> at a fixed amount, no matter what (IE vs FireFox)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, html-table

I have an HTML page containing a table,
my problem is the height of one my `<td>` which is rendered correctly in **IE-8** but incorrectly in **FireFox 20.0.1**

I'm a fan of FireFox myself, specially when it comes to IE :) anyway I have set the height of the `<td>`, containing the word "bottom", to 30px (or 10%; makes no difference) and the upper `<td>` to 90%

The height of bottom `<td>` is shown correctly in FireFox when I reduce contents of the right `<td>`, but when I add more lines of text in the right `<td>`, it (the bottom one) is shown incorrectly(very larger) in FireFox and okay in IE.

What's wrong with my code or very unlikely with FireFox? :)
In other words, I want to always keep the height of the bottom `<td>` to 30px no matter what.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Agent</title>
        <style>
          html, body { height: 100% }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr >
                <td id=properties width="20%" height="90%">
                 top
                </td>
                <td id=step rowspan="2" width="80%" >
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                    right <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td width="20%" height="30px">
                    bottom
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks same to me in both browsers

Comment: Maybe it's your screen resolution, please add some more lines in the right `<td>`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`30px` is not a valid value for `height` attribute for a `td`.  Also note that

> The  height attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

You can either try  (HTML)

```
<td width="20%" height="30">
```

or CSS

```
<td style="width:20%;height:30px">
```

**Syntax is**

```
<td height="pixels|%">
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_height.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and information, however it didn't work, I tried both CSS and HTML version of your code. the result is the same.